# Accessing the recombination map of Drosophila melanogaster

Tags: database, data, recombination, drosophila

I'm looking for some information on the data of a recombination map of *Drosophila melanogaster*. In 2012, an extensive study by [Comeron *et al.*](https://journals.plos.org/plosgenetics/article?id=10.1371/journal.pgen.1002905) appeared saying that they had reconstructed a recombination map for *D. melanogaster*. I want to access the data files themselves, and the Data Availability section of the paper included:

> Estimates of recombination reported in this study are publicly
> available, for any genomic region or gene in *D. melanogaster*, from
> [www.recombination.biology.uiowa.edu](http://www.recombination.biology.uiowa.edu) and [www.recombinome.com](http://www.recombinome.com).

So two websites are listed for where the data can be accessed. But neither site exists anymore. A data file can be downloaded from Comeron's work on FlyBase [here](http://flybase.org/reports/FBrf0233439.html). The problem is, however, this data file only seems to list crossover (CO) recombination rates in windows, but not the same thing for gene conversion (GC) recombination rates, despite both being reported separately in the paper. So this makes me think that there's a lot of supplementary files from Comeron's paper not saved here on the FlyBase page. I found another indication of the limited access there seems to be of Comeron *et al.*'s original files. Reading [this 2019 paper](https://academic.oup.com/gbe/article/11/4/1345/5454723) which appeared to make use of Comeron *et al.*'s recombination map data:

> The resultant *D. simulans* recombination map was used in parallel with
> the *D. melanogaster* recombination map produced by Comeron *et al.*
> (2012), downloaded from the *D. melanogaster* Recombination Rate
> Calculator (Fiston-Lavier *et al.* 2010, last accessed April 19, 2019 ).

So the [paper](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/20452408/) for the Recombination Rate Calculator (RCC) was published in 2010 to introduce this web tool. And when the Comeron et al study came out in 2012, the website incorporated that papers data. And that's how this 2019 paper is accessing that data, ie via the RCC website. The RCC website is old and not updated, as you can only query recombination map coordinates in Release 5 of the *D. melanogaster* genome. But when you do submit a query for the recombination rates of regions of the *Drosophila* genome to the website, you suddenly get these additional columns of information referenced back to the Comeron *et al.* study: minimum, maximum, and average recombination rate over the genome. This is not listed in the FlyBase file at all, and the RCC website doesn't specify if this is CO or GC recombination rates. Also, from what I can see you can't actually download the supplementary data files from the RCC website for yourself either.

So, how can I actually access the full supplementary data from Comeron *et al.*'s original recombination map study of Drosophila? It doesn't seem that there is any sort of full access from the sources listed in the paper, or FlyBase, or the RCC website. If any additional recombination maps have come out since and the data files are available, I'd be happy to use those as well.

EDIT: FlyBase unfortunately doesn't have additional files to those I've found. The Comeron lab also lost some info when those websites went defunct, but will attach some of the per-chromosome recombination amp files to the website in R5 and R6 coordinates.

Comment: We don’t know. Write to the authors of the paper, and if they don’t reply, try writing to FlyBase, which provides excellent professional support.

Comment: @David Thanks for the suggestion, I've sent FlyBase an email and will update if I get what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the original links stopped working, apologies. I have now added a file/link in my current website with per-chromosome recombination maps in R5 and R6 coordinates.
https://comeron.lab.uiowa.edu/recombination-rates

Josep

Answer (score 1):

Josep Comeron is [still at the University of Iowa Biology Department](https://biology.uiowa.edu/people/josep-comeron), and his lab has its own [website](https://comeron.lab.uiowa.edu/). Browsing around, I found [this page](https://comeron.lab.uiowa.edu/recombination-rates) on recombination rates, but no apparent way to access the data. His contact information is available on both the UIowa Biology Dept. page and his lab site, so I suggest emailing or calling him directly to see where the information you're seeking is currently available.

I tried to use the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web) to see if the data from either recombinome.com or the uiowa.edu was archived there. recombinome.com has been [crawled repeatedly](https://web.archive.org/web/20220000000000*/http://www.recombinome.com/), but clicking on some random results from 2013-2015 only gave the main page, with no links to the raw data. [www.recombination.biology.uiowa.edu](http://www.recombination.biology.uiowa.edu) was never archived.

Comment: I originally encountered the same issue trying to access those sites with the Wayback Machine unfortunately.